# Dealing with a string containing multiple character encodings

Tags: python, string, unicode, encoding

I'm not exactly sure how to ask this question really, and I'm no where close to finding an answer, so I hope someone can help me.

I'm writing a Python app that connects to a remote host and receives back byte data, which I unpack using Python's built-in struct module. My problem is with the strings, as they include multiple character encodings. Here is an example of such a string:

"^LThis is an example ^Gstring with multiple ^Jcharacter encodings"

Where the different encoding starts and ends is marked using special escape chars:

- ^L - Latin1
- ^E - Central Europe
- ^T - Turkish
- ^B - Baltic
- ^J - Japanese
- ^C - Cyrillic
- ^G - Greek

And so on... I need a way to convert this sort of string into Unicode, but I'm really not sure how to do it. I've read up on Python's codecs and string.encode/decode, but I'm none the wiser really. I should mention as well, that I have no control over how the strings are outputted by the host.

I hope someone can help me with how to get started on this.

Comment: Does your parser throw any error or are you left with a valid Python string, but with unusable encodings? If so, things can be fixed. Provide an example string, please.

Comment: I mean other example than the above, as the above example has only ASCII characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no built-in functionality for decoding a string like this, since it is really its own custom codec.  You simply need to split up the string on those control characters and decode it accordingly.

Here's a (very slow) example of such a function that handles latin1 and shift-JIS:

```
latin1 = "latin-1"
japanese = "Shift-JIS"

control_l = "\x0c"
control_j = "\n"

encodingMap = {
    control_l: latin1,
    control_j: japanese}

def funkyDecode(s, initialCodec=latin1):
    output = u""
    accum = ""
    currentCodec = initialCodec
    for ch in s:
        if ch in encodingMap:
            output += accum.decode(currentCodec)
            currentCodec = encodingMap[ch]
            accum = ""
        else:
            accum += ch
    output += accum.decode(currentCodec)
    return output
```

A faster version might use str.split, or regular expressions.

(Also, as you can see in this example, "^J" is the control character for "newline", so your input data is going to have some interesting restrictions.)

Answer (score 7):

Here's a relatively simple example of how do it...

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

# Test Data
ENCODING_RAW_DATA = (
    ('latin_1',    'L', u'Hello'),        # Latin 1
    ('iso8859_2',  'E', u'dobrý večer'),  # Central Europe
    ('iso8859_9',  'T', u'İyi akşamlar'), # Turkish
    ('iso8859_13', 'B', u'Į sveikatą!'),  # Baltic
    ('shift_jis',  'J', u'今日は'),        # Japanese
    ('iso8859_5',  'C', u'Здравствуйте'), # Cyrillic
    ('iso8859_7',  'G', u'Γειά σου'),   # Greek
)

CODE_TO_ENCODING = dict([(chr(ord(code)-64), encoding) for encoding, code, text in ENCODING_RAW_DATA])
EXPECTED_RESULT = u''.join([line[2] for line in ENCODING_RAW_DATA])
ENCODED_DATA = ''.join([chr(ord(code)-64) + text.encode(encoding) for encoding, code, text in ENCODING_RAW_DATA])

FIND_RE = re.compile('[\x00-\x1A][^\x00-\x1A]*')

def decode_single(bytes):
    return bytes[1:].decode(CODE_TO_ENCODING[bytes[0]])

result = u''.join([decode_single(bytes) for bytes in FIND_RE.findall(ENCODED_DATA)])

assert result==EXPECTED_RESULT, u"Expected %s, but got %s" % (EXPECTED_RESULT, result)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would write a codec that incrementally scanned the string and decoded the bytes as they came along. Essentially, you would have to separate strings into chunks with a consistent encoding and decode those and append them to the strings that followed them.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely have to split the string first into the substrings wih different encodings, and decode each one separately. Just for fun, the obligatory "one-line" version:

```
import re

encs = {
    'L': 'latin1',
    'G': 'iso8859-7',
    ...
}

decoded = ''.join(substr[2:].decode(encs[substr[1]])
             for substr in re.findall('\^[%s][^^]*' % ''.join(encs.keys()), st))
```

(no error checking, and also you'll want to decide how to handle '^' characters in  substrings)

Comment: You made exactly the same mistake as me!

Answer (score 1):

I don't suppose you have any way of convincing the person who hosts the other machine to switch to unicode?

This is one of the reasons Unicode was invented, after all.

Comment: As I've said, I have no control over the host itself. The host is actually a computer game which my app connects to, and I believe this is how it handles its text-rendering internally.